What's the Agave blockchain and how it's related to Solana?
Currently all the PRs in the Solana repo were closed by bot that points to Agave blockchain. I didn't find any info on what it is and how it's related to Solana blockchain. Could anyone please clarify?

Anza Technology is a new company founded by the core Solana validator engineers, and Agave is their validator client that was forked from the Solana Labs validator.
You can find out more about it at https://www.anza.xyz/#validator

So,  Solana repo  maintainers now all work on Agave repo? will the  Solana repo go to be archived and no update any more?

Yes, and most likely
